# How to increase the height of EditText through code in java?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I am trying to make the editText with increased height through android java code. How to achieve it? Any help is highly appreciated and thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code...

```
ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams mlp = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams)EditText.getLayoutParams();
mlp.height=100;
mlp.width=150;
```

where `EditText` is your `EditText`..

and you can also set Width , margin..etc

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
editTextObject.setHeight(30);
```