# Java: increase the size of Edittextfield

Tags: java, android

trying to increase the size of the edittextfield in java..how can i do that.
Below is my code

```
final EditText address = new EditText(activity);
                if (data.getFavoriteAddress() != null
                        && !data.getFavoriteAddress().trim().equals("")) {
                    address.setText(data.getFavoriteAddress());
                } else {
                    address.setHint(R.string.address);
                }
```

Comment: Question answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7480337/1689695

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can write like this,for increasing edit text size

address.setTextSize(18.0f);

or if you want to increase the edit text field then

EditText address = new EditText(this);
address .setLayoutParams(new EditText .LayoutParams(EditText .LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, EditText .LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

or

EditText address = new EditText(this);
address .setLayoutParams(new EditText.LayoutParams(100,100));

Comment: Hi ..Thanks for the code ..EditText.LayoutParams(100,100)); gives a small box...rest are expanding but not the address field ...

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code

ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams xyz = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams)EditText.getLayoutParams();
xyz.height=150;
xyz.width=200;

Answer (score 0):

try the following code:

```
  ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams mlp = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams)EditText.getLayoutParams();
  mlp.height=100;
  mlp.width=150;
```

Answer (score 0):

better to use 
EditText address = new EditText(this); 
address .setLayoutParams(new EditText .LayoutParams(EditText .LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, EditText .LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

if it small increase your size from 100 to your required size first one is width next one is height.like below

EditText address = new EditText(this); address .setLayoutParams(new EditText.LayoutParams(450,100));